# Audit table with postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I want to do an audit table with triggers in postgresql.

My example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_editorial_audit() 
RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
    INSERT INTO eidt_aud ("code", "name","action","user_id","timestamp")
           VALUES (OLD, OLD, 'D', USER, now());
    RETURN OLD;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    INSERT INTO eidt_aud ("code", "name","action","user_id","timestamp")
           VALUES (NEW, NEW, 'U', USER, now());
    RETURN NEW;
  ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    INSERT INTO eidt_aud ("code", "name","action","user_id","timestamp")
           VALUES (NEW, NEW, 'I', USER, now());
    RETURN NEW;
  END IF;
  RETURN NULL;
END;

$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'; ;

CREATE TRIGGER tb_editorial_tg_audit AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON tb_edit FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_edit_audit();
```

But I want to do something different:
I want to insert the row in the table of data with the data of the original editorial table if it does not exist, and it is updated in the audit table if it already exists in it. To always have the last state and not each of the states.

Thanks!

Comment: So why not just store the timestamp on the actual table itself?

Comment: How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

So why not just store the timestamp on the actual table itself?

```
CREATE TABLE AS (... myAuditTimestamp timestamp);
```

Or, add the column to a pre-existing table

```
ALTER TABLE foo ADD COLUMN (myAuditTimestamp timestamp);
```

Then use a `TRIGGER` to `UPDATE` the timestamp field. Then the audit field is *ALWAYS* the newest row data, because it's actually on the row. If you go down this route you don't even have to create the `PROCEDURE` the trigger calls, you can use [`SPI`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/contrib-spi.html) `moddatetime()`

> F.34.5. moddatetime — Functions for Tracking Last Modification Time
>
> **moddatetime() is a trigger** that stores the current time into a timestamp field. This can be useful for tracking the last modification time of a particular row within a table. To use, create a BEFORE UPDATE trigger using this function. Specify a single trigger argument: the name of the column to be modified. The column must be of type timestamp or timestamp with time zone. There is an example in moddatetime.example.

Comment: I need to do with triggers

Comment: this is with triggers.